# C# - Do EventSource Providers have to follow the Name-Product-Component naming pattern

Tags: c#, .net, events, trace, etw

I see in documentation that the proper naming convention for a event provider should be **< CompanyName>/< ProductName>/< Component>** as per documentation [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vancem/2013/08/10/the-eventsource-nuget-package-and-support-for-the-windows-event-log-channel-support/):

> Do use the EventSourceAttribute’s Name property to provide a descriptive, qualified name for the ETW event provider represented by your event source. The default is the short name of your event source type, which can easily lead to collisions, as ETW provider names share one machine-wide namespace. An example of a good provider name “--”. Following this 3-element convention will ensure Event Viewer displays your event logs in a logical folder hierarchy: “Application and Services
>     Logs/< CompanyName>/< Product>/< Component>”.

Is it possible to create a stucture containing a company and multiple products?

I am trying to understand the behavior as when I register two manifests in the format of "CompanyName-Product' they will show up in the logs as two separate logs and not nest them under the CompanyName root.

However if I include a component name with such as "CompanyName-Product-Compontent1" each then they will properly nest under the root. Is it not possible to create a log structure without components?

For example take Microsoft's logs:

```
Microsoft 
   --> Windows
       -->.....

Microsoft
   --> SQLServerDataTools
```

I can see that every component more or less goes under the Windows directory but it seems that the provider names that just have the company and product without a component such as "Microsoft-SQLServerDataTools" goes into its own log. Is there a way I can nest this under the same company name?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to follow this approach, but is the recommended way to make it more organized and easy to maintain, otherwise you would end up with random names like 'mycompany-product', 'mycompany.product', 'mycompanyproduct', 'product-mycompany' and would be painfull to manage, as they don't follow a pattern. The naming is just a recommendation in this case and you put the name you want.

Regarding the eventsources, each name is a different entity with their own guid, if you see them nested, is probably because the tooling you are using nest them based on this approach, but they don't depend on each other.

To manage them, you can follow two approaches:

**Create one event source per component\service:**
This approach, will generate one independent manifest for each of your event sources, and you will manage them isolated of each other. You can extend your service without fear of braking others. You can also filter them in isolation by their name or GUID.

**Create one event source and share among all service:**
This way, you will create a big event source with your product name and share among components, this approach is a bit delicate to maintain, as you have to keep the version in sync with your projects, and changes will propagate to all components, to separate internal event for specific components you can use Keywords. I wouldn't recommend this approach.